# Wait until second Gtk3 window has been closed, with blocking the first window (Pyhton, Gtk, Linux)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, gtk3

I have a main window with a button, which opens a second window upon clicking onto the button (see working example below). I would like to 'block' the first main window (e.g.,  greying out) and to wait until the second has been closed (see comment 'wait here').  What must I do?

I'm sorry, I could not find any hints in the Internet, this is why I ask here.

Thanks in advance for some help.

```
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class SecondWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Window 2")
        self.set_border_width(50)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Close second window")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Window_2: button clicked")
        self.close()

class FirstWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="MAIN --Window 1 --")
        self.set_border_width(100)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Open second window")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Second window")
        win_2 = SecondWindow()
        win_2.show_all()

        #
        # Wait here !
        #

        print("After second window has been closed")

win = FirstWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Use `Gtk.Dialog`

This can be achieved using a `Gtk.Dialog`. Fortunately, there's not much you need to change in your code; just a few things that are different about handling `Dialog`s. A full working example will be at the bottom of this answer.

#### Changing your `SecondWindow` class

In order for your `SecondWindow` class to work with `Dialog`, you need to change a couple things. First, obviously, is making it inherit from `Gtk.Dialog` instead of `Gtk.Window`. Second, since `Dialogs` need to have a parent window that they can "block", you'll need to add a `parent` parameter to your `SecondWindow.__init__()` method, and pass it to the `parent` argument when you call `super().__init__()`:

```py
...
class SecondWindow(Gtk.Dialog): # Inherit from Dialog
    def __init__(self, parent): # Add a `parent` parameter
        super().__init__(parent=parent, title="Window 2") # Use the `parent` parameter
...
```

#### The content area

Another difference between `Gtk.Dialog` and `Gtk.Window` is that `Gtk.Dialog` comes with a `Gtk.Box` already inside it, which you then place your children in. To get this box, you can call `dialog.get_content_area()`, and then add your button to it:

```py
...
self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Close second window")
self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
self.area = self.get_content_area() # Get the dialog's content area
self.area.add(self.button) # Add the button to the content area
...
```

#### Changing window management methods

Lastly, when using a `Dialog`, you need to modify the way you open and close your secondary window.

In order to *open* a `Dialog` properly, you need to call its `run()` method after calling `show_all()`. The `run()` method makes sure the `Dialog` blocks its parent window until it is closed:

```py
...
win_2 = SecondWindow(self)
win_2.show_all()
win_2.run() # Run the dialog
...
```

In order to *close* a dialog properly, you can call `destroy()` instead of `close()` (`close()` doesn't immediately close the dialog):

```py
...
def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
    print("Window_2: button clicked")
    self.destroy() # Close the dialog
...
```

Also, in order for the <kbd>X</kbd> button in the corner of your dialog to work properly, you need to connect the `destroy()` method to the `"delete-event"` signal:

```py
...
self.set_border_width(50)
self.connect("delete-event", lambda *_: self.destroy())
...
```

The `lambda *_` is there to catch any arguments that the event might pass to `destroy()`.

### The final result

Here is a full working modification of your code, making use of the changes described above:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class SecondWindow(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent=parent, title="Window 2")
        self.set_border_width(50)
        self.connect("delete-event", lambda *_: self.destroy())

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Close second window")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.area = self.get_content_area()
        self.area.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Window_2: button clicked")
        self.destroy()

class FirstWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="MAIN --Window 1 --")
        self.set_border_width(100)

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Open second window")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Second window")
        win_2 = SecondWindow(self)
        win_2.show_all()
        win_2.run()

        print("After second window has been closed")

win = FirstWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```